# Can I use HashMap of characters in place of String?

Tags: java, string, data-structures, hashmap

I want to have a function to build a String from inputted characters and stop building if it gets an input character that it contains.

I know I can use `String.contains()` for this but I am learning about HashMaps and am wondering if a faster way to do this could be storing the inputted characters in a HashMap and using the `HashMap.contains()` method.

Comment: Interesting idea. A few problems I can think of: The hashmap doesn't maintain order by default, so there is a lot of custom handling involved; converting back to a string for example requires a lot of overhead; you need a lot of characters (few thousend) for the hashmap to outperform an iterative approuch (which string is by default); when `contains` is not used A stupidly amount of times, it propably isn't worth the extra performance needed to create the hashmap-string in the first place

Comment: If your string is, say, just a few hundred chars long, performance won’t matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set` would be a good data structure to use here.

Just take note of 1 thing though,

If you need `case-sensitive` search then you can use a `HashSet`.
Example

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Else, if you need `case-insensitive` search then a `TreeSet`.
Example

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap::containsKey` is [O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923251/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-hashmap-containskey-in-java), `String::contains` [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089558/what-is-the-big-o-of-string-contains-in-java). The implementation may change dependending of the JVM version but it's more something like O(n).

So yes, using an `HashMap` to look for a value should be *faster* (on small data you'll probably don't notice a difference) than calling `String::contains`. But a Map stores a key and a value, if you don't care about the value, you can use a `Set` (be careful, all the values are unique in this type of collection) because `Set::contains` is [O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247854/what-is-the-time-complexity-performance-of-hashset-contains-in-java).

---

As @n247s mentionned in the comment. Except if you really have a performance issue, `String::contains` should works fine and make the code simpler to read.

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap<>** is just a class that extends the **Map<>** interface, you can use **containsKey()** or **containsValue()**. If you want to loop through the values in the **HashMap**, you can use the **HashMaps.values()** method and concat/add the value to the String.

UNTESTED:

```
int count = -1;
String new = "";
for (char c : map.values()) {
    count++;
    if (string.charAt(count).equals(c))
      break;
    new.concat(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Approach would be to use a `Set` if you do not care about insertion order, but if you do, there is a `LinkedHashSet` you should use, that will keep your characters in order of insertion.

Here is a link to the `LinkedHashSet` doc.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

But if you actually want to use the `key` / `value` pair of the `HashMap`, you can indeed use a `HashMap<Character, Character>`, then you can check with  `map.containsKey() O(1)`, and `map.containsValue() O(n)` keep in mind since `containsValue()` will use `O(n)`, it's better to just check `String::contain` in that scenario. And if you care about insertion order, there is also a `LinkedHashMap` that will do that for you. Link to the doc bellow
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html